# Duplicate Values Returning With Distinct and Subquery

Tags: sql, duplicates, databricks

I'll preface with I don't know much, but I do know one column is causing duplicates when I run sum().

Long story short, I need to reference two tables, one holds a filter value that the other relies on. However, in the joined table that holds the minute changes in one column are causing data integrity issues.

Any tips on how to pull [slcitemnumber] sum without the same column [productnumber] causing duplicates due to [productlongname]?

[slcitemnumber] and [productnumber] should be unique.

Thank you all!

| year(salesdate) | slceitemnumber | productlongname | sum(transactionamount) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 141630 | 141630 Candy Cp StrwBnMx KCup142g | $386,264.97 |
| 2021 | 141630 | 141630 Candy Cp StrwBnMx KCup151g | $12,721.25 |
| 2021 | 142156 | 142156 CH2021 WhiteChoc Snwmnbmb | $21,107.32 |
| 2021 | 142156 ​ | 142156 Stride Sour Patch Wtrmln 14pc | $18.32 |

```
select distinct year(a.salesdate) 
  -- ,Zonename
,a.slcitemnumber
, a.productlongname
, sum(a.transactionamount)
from
  digital.ejtransdatafuelrewards a
  inner join (
    select
      distinct corporatebrandtype,
      productnumber
    from
      digital.dimproduct
    where
      corporatebrandtype = 'PB'
      and enddate > '2020-01-01'
      group by
      corporatebrandtype,
      productnumber
  ) b
 on a.slcitemnumber = b.productnumber
where
  salesdate between '2021-1-1'
  and '2021-12-31'
  and a.zonename not in ('Team 2')
  and a.slcitemnumber != '-99999'
  and char_length(slcitemnumber) = 6
  and a.slcitemnumber is not null
group by
  a.slcitemnumber
,year(a.salesdate)
,a.productlongname
having
  sum(transactionamount) > 0
```

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY removes all duplicates.

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Thank you jarlh, I seemed to have fixed it after hacking away until it worked. I had to reverse the logic on which table was joined